# Windows Azure Storage Exception with Connection String Specifying Account Name and Account Key

Tags: azure-storage, .net-standard

I am adding Windows Azure Storage to my ASP.Net application. I am using NetStandard 1.4 and am building on MacOS.

I have the following as my connection string, as recommended by [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-configure-connection-string):

DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=XXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXX

I am connecting with a new Azure Storage account and have confirmed that my account name and account key are correct. Right before the call to create the table, I added a WriteLine to display the CloudStorageAccount's connection string URI just to make sure it is correct. It has the hostname.

I am getting the following error when performing "dotnet run".

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error
>   occurred while sending the request.) --->
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: An error occurred
>   while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
>   An error occurred while sending the request. --->
>   System.Net.Http.CurlException: Couldn't resolve host name

Setting explicit table storage endpoint (TableEndpoint=XXX.table.core.windows.net) didn't work either.

Are there any other reasons why Curl will fail when connecting to XXX.table.core.windows.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try capture the network trace for troubleshooting? And try to ping XXX.table.core.windows.net? Is it because the DNS cache not refreshed?

Comment: There was an issue with my Azure Storage account / setup. I deleted it and created a new one and it worked.